# Should all MassTransit messages be correlated in general?

Tags: masstransit

I'm trying to figure out when to use message correlation.  It seems to me like it would be best to make a coding standard that all messages should be correlated unless you have some reason not to.

Is there any reason why this would be a bad idea?

Answer (score 0):

You really should have some way to correlation messages for a number of reason. Implementing `CorrelatedBy<T>` isn't really a requirement. I would just use whatever makes sense for your system. It could just be a `TransactionId` or something similar.

However, for tracking, research, idempotence, and sagas you do really want some way to correlate messages. Like I said, just whatever makes sense to your world.